# Split large CSV file based on column value cardinality

Tags: awk, split, large-files

I have a large CSV file with following line format:

```
c1,c2
```

I would like to split the original file in two files as follows:

1. One file will contain the lines where the value of c1 appears exactly once in the file.
2. Another file will contain the lines where the value of c1 appears twice or more in the file.

Any idea how it can be done?

For example, if the original file is:

```
1,foo
2,bar
3,foo
4,bar
2,foo
1,bar
```

I would like to produce the following files:

```
3,foo
4,bar
```

and

```
1,foo
2,bar
2,foo
1,bar
```

Comment: how large is "large" - because the only way you can really do this is by inspecting your file twice - you won't know the count of a particular value until you've finished the whole lot. Thus you either need to read it twice, or hold the whole lot in memory.

Comment: Also: How important is retaining ordering?

Answer (score 1):

this one-liner generates two files `o1.csv and o2.csv`

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{print >"o"(a[$1]==1?"1":"2")".csv"}' file file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
1,foo
2,bar
3,foo
4,bar
2,foo
1,bar

kent$  awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}{print >"o"(a[$1]==1?"1":"2")".csv"}' f f

kent$  head o*
==> o1.csv <==
3,foo
4,bar

==> o2.csv <==
1,foo
2,bar
2,foo
1,bar
```

#### Note

- awk reads your file twice, instead of saving whole file in memory
- the order of the file is retained

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you mean by big, this might work for you. 
It has to hold the lines, in associative array done,  until it sees 
2nd use, or until the end of file. When a 2nd use is seen the remembered
data is changed to "!" to avoid printing it again on a 3rd and later match.

```
>file2
awk -F, '
{ if(done[$1]!=""){
    if(done[$1]!="!"){
     print done[$1]
     done[$1] = "!"
    }
    print
  }else{ 
   done[$1] = $0
   order[++n] = $1
  }
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
   out = done[order[i]]
   if(out!="!")print out >>"file2"
  }
}
' <csvfile >file1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd break out Perl for this job

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my %count_of;
my @lines; 

open ( my $input, '<', 'your_file.csv' ) or die $!; 

#read the whole file
while ( <$input> ) {
   my ( $c1, $c2 ) = split /,/;
   $count_of{$c1}++; 
   push ( @lines, [ $c1 , $c2 ] ); 
}
close ( $input ); 

print "File 1:\n";
#filter any single elements
foreach my $pair ( grep { $count_of{$_ -> [0]} < 2 } @lines ) {
    print join (",", @$pair );
}

print "File 2:\n"; 
#filter any repeats. 
foreach my $pair ( grep { $count_of{$_ -> [0]} > 1 } @lines ) {
    print join (",", @$pair );
}
```

This will hold the whole file in memory, but given your data - you don't save much space by double processing it and maintaining a count.

However you *could* do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %count_of;

open( my $input, '<', 'your_file.csv' ) or die $!;

#read the whole file counting "c1"
while (<$input>) {
    my ( $c1, $c2 ) = split /,/;
    $count_of{$c1}++;
}

open( my $output_single, '>', "output_uniques.csv" ) or die $!;
open( my $output_dupe,   '>', "output_dupes.csv" )   or die $!;

seek( $input, 0, 0 );
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    my ($c1) = split( ",", $line );
    if ( $count_of{$c1} > 1 ) {
        print {$output_dupe} $line;
    }
    else {
        print {$output_single} $line;
    }
}

close($input);
close($output_single);
close($output_dupe);
```

This will minimise memory occupancy, by only retaining the count - it reads the file first to count the `c1` values, and then processes it a second time and prints lines to different outputs.